# Resolution of an inequality on integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, inequalities

I’m trying to resolve respect to $k$ the following inequality, 
$$
k\left(\log k +\log \log k-\alpha+O\left(\frac{\log \log k}{\log k}\right)\right)\geq x,
$$ 
in order to obtain, under the condition $k\leq x$, that
$$
\ k\geq \dfrac{x}{\log x}\left(1+\dfrac{\alpha+o(1)}{\log x}\right)
$$ 
is this possible?

Comment: What is the context of this? Is this coming from an explicit version of the Prime Number Theorem?

Comment: I want to get a explicit upper bound of Prime counting function

Comment: That was my guess. Have you looked at the various papers by Dusart? His paper "Explicit estimates of some functions over primes"  and others may have bounds which do what you want. http://www.unilim.fr/pages_perso/pierre.dusart/Publications.html Has a list of a variety of his papers many which have bounds which may be relevant.

Comment: I know Dusart’s work, but I want to get some one via an elementary method.

Comment: In that case, how are you getting your bound on p_k to start with? I don't know of any elementary proof of the PNT which gives an error term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\ka{\kappa}$
Let $a:=\alpha$. Let $f$ be a function such that 
$$f(k)=k\Big(\ln k +\ln\ln k-a+O\Big(\frac{\ln\ln k}{\ln k}\Big)\Big)
=k\big(\ln k +\ln\ln k-a+o(1)\big)$$
as $k\to\infty$. 
For any real $b$ and $x>0$, let 
$$\ka:=\ka_b(x):=\frac x{\ln x}\Big(1+\frac b{\ln x}\Big).$$
We have to show that

> for any real $b\in(-\infty,a)$, if $x>0$ is large enough and $f(k)\ge x$, then $k\ge\ka_b(x)$.

Take any real $b\in(-\infty,a)$ and then take any $c\in(b,a)$. Let
$$f_c(k):=k\big(\ln k +\ln\ln k-c\big).$$ 
Let $x\to\infty$. Then 
$$\ln\ka=\ln x-\ln\ln x+o(1)\sim\ln x,$$
$$\ln\ln\ka=\ln\ln x+o(1),$$
$$\ln\ka+\ln\ln\ka=\ln x+o(1),$$
$$f_c(\ka_b(x))=\frac x{\ln x}\Big(1+\frac b{\ln x}\Big)\big(\ln x-c+o(1)\big) \\
=\frac x{\ln x}\Big(1+\frac b{\ln x}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{c-o(1)}{\ln x}\Big)\ln x \\ 
=x\Big(1+\frac{b-c-o(1)}{\ln x}\Big)<x$$ 
for large enough $x>0$.

Now suppose that $f(k)\ge x$. Then $x\to\infty$ implies $k\to\infty$, because $f$ is bounded on any bounded subset of the set of all natural numbers. Therefore, for all large enough $x>0$ we have $f(k)\le f_c(k)$ and, because $f_c(k)$ is increasing in large enough $k$, we also have $f_c(k)\le f_c(\ka_b(x))$ if $k<\ka_b(x)$, so that 
$$f(k)\le f_c(k)\le f_c(\ka_b(x))<x,$$
which means that indeed, if $x>0$ is large enough and $f(k)\ge x$, then $k\ge\ka_b(x)$.

Comment: It’s not classic but it works normally, thanks.

Comment: The problem is I must now have an effective version.